# Vertically sorting with `collection_check_boxes`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of cities loaded by my controller with `@cities = City.order :name`.

And display those in check boxes in my view with:

```
f.collection_check_boxes :cities_ids, @cities, :id, :name
```

Each check box is wrapped in a 33% wide div, Which output them arranged like this:

```
city_A   |   city_B   |   city_C
city_D   |   city_E   |   city_F
city_G   |   city_H   |   city_I
city_J   |            |
```

I am trying to sort `@cities` before passing it to the builder, so it can be aligned vertically on 3 columns:

```
city_A   |   city_E   |   city_H
city_B   |   city_F   |   city_I
city_C   |   city_G   |   city_J
city_D   |            |
```

After trying different combinations of `Enumerable` and `Array` methods (and a nose-bleed and 2 aspirins) I decided to ask you guys. Thanks!

**Temporary solution**

By writing a helper I can fix the problem, if you guys can come up with a better more compact solution I would appreciate. Check this out

```
def per_column(records, number_of_columns = 3)
  collection = records.dup
  result = []

  return collection if records.count <= number_of_columns

  # Build columns
  number_of_columns.times do |column_index|
    number_of_items = (collection.count.to_f / (number_of_columns - column_index)).ceil
    result << collection.slice!(0, number_of_items)
  end

  # Ensure each columns has same number of lines
  result.each {|column| column << nil until column.count == result[0].count }

  # Transpose
  result.transpose.flatten.compact
end
```

Then I just call

```
f.collection_check_boxes :cities_ids, per_column(@cities), :id, :name
```

Seems to work for any number of records. Once again if you can point me to a more elegant solution I would appreciate

Comment: `City.order('name DESC')`? `order` take string not sym http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-order

Comment: Works fine with sym :) Thanks anyway

Comment: yeah you're right I just looked through the source but `sym` will make it default to `ASC`

Comment: anyway back to your question may be you could use `group_by`?
like `@cities.group_by{|c| c.id%3 }`

Comment: Hmm, that wont work, cause the sorting is done by :name. I realize my question is misleading cause I'm referring to city_id. I edit it now to make it clearer

Comment: And even so, the `group_by` would work only if there is a number of records that is a multiple of 3 (I tried that before posting my question). It you got 10 record for example the last record comes in 4rth position

Comment: yeah that occurred to me last night as well… here is my new solution: first get the divider `divider = (@cities.length/3).ceil`  `@cities.group_by.with_index {|c,i| (i/column_group)%3 }` hope this help :)

Comment: Edited my question with a temporary solution, if you have time to check it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way of doing this would probably be to wrap each "column" in a div, and not each checkbox.

However, if that's not viable - and it isn't if you want to use `collection_check_boxes` - check out the [in_columns gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/in_columns) that I just released.

That should allow you to do

```
f.collection_check_boxes :cities_ids, InColumns.columnize(@cities, 3).flatten.compact, :id, :name
```

or

```
f.collection_check_boxes :cities_ids, @cities.in_columns(3).flatten.compact, :id, :name
```

if you use the `Array` extension in the gem.

Comment: Now that looks good :) but I got the same issue: if the number of record is not divisible by 3 then the output is scramble. I post an issue in your git now

Comment: Note for anyone that pass by with the exact same problem: Jakob updated his gem so it completely answer to the situation. in_columns gems can be used with Rails form collection helper/builder to display stuff per columns. Nice and easy. Great job

Answer (score 4):

Hey I just implemented this one myself! In order to list collection_check_boxes items in your form in columns, use a little CSS.

1) Create a CSS class for your 3 columns:

```
.form-3-col {
  -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
  column-count: 3; 
}
```

I recommend putting this class in a stylesheet called `forms.css.scss` which you require in your `application.css` with `*= require forms`

You'll find some useful style add-ons such as column spacing here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp

2) Implement the CSS class in your form:

```
 <li>
  <%= f.label :city %>
  <div class="form-3-col">
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :cities_ids, @cities, :id, :name %>
  </div> <!-- form-3-col -->
 </li>
```

Notice how the `div` is wrapped around only the `f.collection_check_boxes` erb tag as it will columnize anything inside of it.